# How to target mobile heights using CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I always worked with widths using CSS. Ex:

```
@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) {
...
}
```

I want to target mobiles that have different heights (569px and 480px) that have 320px width.

I tried:

```
@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) and (max-height: 568px) {
}

@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) and (max-height: 480px) {
}
```

and it didn't work for me.

I tried

```
@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) and (max-height: 568px) {
}

@media (min-width :  240px) and (max-width : 320px ) and (miin-height: 568px) and (max-height: 480px) {
}
```

I have this in my head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=0" />
```

not sure if it has something to do with all of this. 
but should I use

```
height=device-height initial-scale=1
```

in this tag too?

Comment: try just using max-height only....

Comment: Did that too.. not working

Comment: maybe if I separate both to 

(max-height: 568px) { ...} and (max-height: 480px) {...}

Comment: Thank you dude, 
You can comment as an answer if you like :) 
Worked!

Comment: Glad to help, you may now delete the question....

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

and add to class this css

```
width: 100%; height: 100vh;
```

for ex:

```
.slider { width: 100%; height: 100vh; }
```

with height 100vh you can have a div height like device screen